# How do I solve "runtime error type 13 Type mismatch" in excel VBA when clearing contents?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, macros

I have some VBA code that clears contents from several cells. Most of those cells have data validation so that a value must be selected from a list of options (yes, no, NA), the rest are open for any type of data.

When I click the button for running the code for the first time, I get the following error (If I click End, I don´t get the error again when clicking the button):

[image]

I´ve checked other questions and googled the problem. It seems to have something to do with adding values of different types, but since I´m only clearing contents this should not be the problem.

This is my Code. **The error happenes on the first clearcontent (line 8 for cells C5:D5)**:

```
Sub ReiniciarRef()
'
' ReiniciarRef Macro
'

'
    Range("C5:D5").Select
    Selection.ClearContents 
    Range("C7").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C9:G10").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C13:G13").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C16:G16").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C18").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C23:D23").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C25").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C27:G28").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C31:G31").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C34:G34").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C36").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C41:D41").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C43").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C45:G46").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C49:G49").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C52:G52").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C54").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C59:D59").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C61").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C63:G64").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C67:G67").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C70:G70").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C72").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C77:D77").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C79").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C81:G82").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C85:G85").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C88:G88").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C90").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C5:D5").Select
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Exactly which line(s) are throwing the error?  Which cells are causing it to fail, and what are the data types of those cells?  What have you attempted already to solve it, and what were the results?

Comment: I edited to show the lines and cells. I stated the data is text from a drop down list, and I have no idea what to try because I don´t see the mismatch.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the beginning of your sub and then step through it until you find the (first) line that throws the error.  Perhaps check out this SU question: [How do I debug Excel / OpenOffice / LibreOffice macros - getting started](http://superuser.com/questions/794590/how-do-i-debug-excel-openoffice-libreoffice-macros-getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably being thrown by the validation which is triggered "on change". Try:

```
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Range("C5:D5").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    [...]

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```